# android- return custom class in onCreateView

Tags: android, imageview, invalidation

i have class inherit from SherlockFragment , in its onCreateView method i need return custom class 
this view download image from web and i make custom class to make it zoom-able 
the problem its in first open to this view it back with default image not downloaded one

i have class to create view called create_schedule_view();
it change schedule_bitmap with downloaded one but i still have problem with update view automatic with new image 
any ideas 
thank you 
my code

```
 public class Schedule_Fragment extends SherlockFragment{
  @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                Bundle savedInstanceState) {

            View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_schedule, container,
                    false);

            schedule_bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.schedule);

            schedule_image_view = (ImageView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.schedule);

            get_schedule_DB(Student_id);
            if (image_byte == null || network.isConnectingToInternet()) {
                get_schedule_WEB(Student_id);

            }

            create_schedule_view();
            setHasOptionsMenu(true);
            sanboxview = new SandboxView(getActivity(), schedule_bitmap);
            sanboxview.invalidate();
            return sanboxview;
        }
}
```